# wordpress mysqli_fetch_array not showing single quote in results

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

when i get my results, single quotes come up as special characters (questions mark ?) Is there a way to make them display correctly?  this is my code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $category1 = $row['category'];
    $quer = "Select * from categories where id = $category1";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$quer) or die ("Unable to execute query: $quer <br>Reason: It broke here!" . mysql_error()); 

    $category = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    ?>
    <span Style="Font-size: 25px; "><?php print $category['name']?></span><br>
    <p><span class="headerLink">QUESTION</span><br>
    <div class="bodytext" align="justify"><?php print  $row['question']; ?></div></p>
    <p><span class="headerLink">ANSWER</span><br>
    <div class="bodytext" align="justify"><?php print $row['answer']; ?></div></p>
    <div align="center"><a href="#top" class="topLink">&bull;&nbsp; Top &nbsp;&bull;</a></div><br>

<?php
    } ?>
```

Comment: What character(s) _exactly_ do you mean by “single quotes”? Most likely this is a character encoding issue.

Comment: the single quote character ( John's name shows as John?s name)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of things you can try:

set the doc charset in the `<head></head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and use `htmlentities`

```
 <span Style="Font-size: 25px; "><?php echo htmlentities($category['name'])?></span>
```

you should also be using the `$wpdb` object to filter for sql injection